# How do i read values from an html form into variables for javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use the values that I select in a list be used as a variables.

I have been trying different approches one is with the window.onload but i don't think that will work.

html

```
    <form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">

        <select name="Y" id="IDlist">   
        <option value="empty"> ID</option>
        </select> 

        <select name="X" id="namelist">
        <option value="empty"> Name</option>
        </select> 
        <input  type="submit" value="Check"  />

        </form>
```

javascript

```
    var chosen_name = '';
        var chosen_ID='';
        window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function () {
        chosen_name = document.getElementById("namelist");
        chosen_ID = document.getElementById("IDlist");

          console.log(chosen_ID.value + " and " + chosen_name.value + " please work.")};
        return [chosen_name, chosen_ID]
      };
        document.write(chosen_name);
```

i generally expect some the chosen name not to be empty. any suggesstion will be welcomed. thank yoou

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to have a javascript function and call it on the Check button after that write the values to the screen

```js
var chosen_name = '';
var chosen_ID='';

function UpdateValues(){
  chosen_ID = document.getElementById("IDlist").value;
  chosen_name = document.getElementById("namelist").value;
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = chosen_ID + "<br/>" + chosen_name;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    <select name="Y" id="IDlist">   
      <option value="emptyID"> ID</option>
    </select> 

    <select name="X" id="namelist">
      <option value="emptyName"> Name</option>
    </select> 
    <input  type="button" onclick="UpdateValues()" value="Check"  />
</form>

<p id="res"></p>
```

Comment: would it be possible to update the chosen_ID and chosen_name in global variables without refreshin the page into a new one?

Comment: @NadirSAHLLAL yes in fact we are not refreshing the page at all I will update the answer so it would be more clear to you

Comment: yes thank you, i understand. the values chosen_name and chosen_ID still are ' ', outside of the function. is there no possibility to have them stay as the chosen file.

Comment: the thing is that i want the chosen values to kinda point to an object in an json list. that's why i want a global variable.

Comment: @NadirSAHLLAL sorry i did not understand you correctly. do you want to store the variables in somewhere to retrieve it later on?

Comment: yes, that was the idea but, i solved it by creating different function to do the job. Thank you for all the help. now just need to create different leaflet problems. thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to enforce people selecting a name before submitting:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form')
const name = form.name

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const nameValue = form.name.value
  
  if(nameValue) {
    window.customForm = {name : nameValue}
  }
  
})
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <select name="id" id="IDlist">   
    <option value="empty"> ID</option>
  </select> 
  <select name="name" id="namelist">
  <option value="">Name</option>
  <option value="john">John</option>
  </select> 
  <input  type="submit" value="Check"  />
</form>
```

Comment: I want to be able from the to stock dynmicaly the values chosend from the form in a global variable that i could use later in my script.

Comment: just edited to match your requirements, bear in mind polluting the global scope is not a good practice which can sound cliche but is not as if the app gets bigger it easily gets unmanageable

Answer (score 0):

So There was no actual practical way to do what i was asking.
In the end I used functions and just did a simple call when ever i need to use a variable.
Not the clearedt of answers.(sorry)